# 2 column CSV file to Javascript Dictionary

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary (javascript) from a CSV file.

Say I have a CSV file that contains something like this:

```
key1, value1
key2, value2
key3, value3
```

How could I turn it into a dictionary with keys and values?

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any special characters:

```
const dictionary = new Map();

str.split("\n").forEach(line => {
    const [key, val] = line.split(", ");
    dictionary.set(key, val);
});

dictionary.get("key2"); // value2
```

You might want to properly parse the CSV if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "dictionaries" in JavaScript, but you can create a dictionary-type variable using objects.

I wrote a node example that reads a local CSV file, using part of HTMHell's answer for line splits:

```
'use strict'
const fs = require('fs');

var myDictionary = {};

fs.readFile('data.csv', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  var lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    const [key, val] = line.split(', ');
    console.log(key, val);
    myDictionary[key] = val;
  });
  console.log(myDictionary);
});
```

The object will look like:
{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3'}

For serverless web apps, you will need to create another method to send the CSV file to javascript, but parsing data is the same.

References:

- [JavaScript "Dictionaries"](https://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/javascript-basics-how-to-create-a-dictionary-with-keyvalue-pairs)
- [Node.js FS to read CSVs](https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/28457/using-fs-to-read-in-a-csv)
- [File reading line-by-line](https://attacomsian.com/blog/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-nodejs)